# easeljs animate forward and reverse within the canvas

Tags: javascript, easeljs

Need some advice on easeljs sprite animation, from the [demo they provided](http://www.createjs.com/demos/easeljs/spritesheet)

How do I do a forward and reverse of the running guy within the canvas, from the ticker event?

Answer (score 0):

The movement is just incrementing the x position.

```
// New position is the current position, plus 150 pixels
var position = grant.x + 150 * deltaS;
// The delta is just a multiplier to keep the movement independent of the framerate.

// Then "Grant" is set to the new position, unless the position is past
// the right side of the canvas, in which case it is set to the left side again
// (to wrap)
grant.x = (position >= w + grantW) ? -grantW : position;
```

To reverse the animation, you can reverse the math

```
var position = grant.x - 150 * deltaS; // Move backwards
grant.x = (position < 0) ? w : position; // Put on far right
```

Then you can flip the sprite horizontally to make him go the other way.

```
grant.scaleX = -1;
```

You can take the same approach with everything else. Note that in the demo, the sprite is not really moving relative to the ground, background etc, it is just set up as a parallax effect. You might want to take a different approach if you want to make something more interactive.

Comment: Thanks Lanny, the reverse works but I can't seemed to make it turn back to forward after it reaches at one end.

Comment: The demo just wraps the position. You would need to change it to check the bounds, and change it's behaviour instead. For example: `if (grant.x < 0) { moveRightAction(); } else if (grant.x > w) { moveLeftAction(); }`